# Jquery Offset Scrolldown

Tags: jquery

i have a One Page Scrolling Site with `Masthead` and `Affix` for the Nav. When i scroll down, the Headline will be overlapped from my nav. When i scroll up the position is correct.

Here is my page:

[Website](http://digitalartworx.net/medi/test.html)

```
$(function() {
     $('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
       var $anchor = $(this);
       $('html, body').stop().animate({
          scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
       });
    });
});
```

Comment: Don't get it what's wrong (ffox) :P  Check under FFOX and chrome if the problem is the same. Also menu nav color should be brighter on hover :P

Comment: Hi,theres is something wrong with the scrolling. When you open the site and click on "Einstieg" it scrolls to the first Anker. But the headline "Zur Person" ist not shown with enought offset to top. Then you click on the second navigation point, the offset to the nav is ok. Only the first click on a navigation point is not correct. i am using a fixed nav.

Comment: So Andre, Have You fixed Your problem - question is still opened. :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. Change the old code in  file: js/main.js

```
$('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
// modification here
    var difference = 0;
    if ($('#nav').hasClass('affix-top')) {
      difference = 65;
    }

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top-difference  // modification here
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
        var test = $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top;
        console.log(test);
    });
```

While You're on top of Your page, and script is computing where window should be scrolled to, div#nav  is still part of the page so it's height get's to the callculations.